# Folder diff tool that allows easy comparison of large number of files

Tags: comparison

I'm trying to verify that a tool to export data from one source control platform to a second works properly before we spend money on a non-demo license.  The demo version only exports the first half of each file.  As a result a folder diff will show every file is changed (truncated at 50%).

Since I have several hundred files in my application checking each one at a time isn't practical.  What I'm looking for is a tool that will let me arrow down the list of files in the folder diff view and automatically show a file diff when the file is present on both the left and right hand sides.  Alternately being able to select groups of ~10-20 files in the folder view and launch separate file comparison windows for each in a single action would be acceptable.

I've tried DiffMerge, KDiff, BeyondCompare, and WinMerge; but haven't been able to find an option to do what I want.  Especially in the latter two it's possible that the feature exists but I'm just not finding it since I've never used them before today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [meld](http://meldmerge.org/), specifically:

```
meld dir1 dir2
```

will highlight files with differences. In some interfaces the differences can then also be shown by double clicking on the files. On others selecting the files and then selecting compare is needed to open the side-by-side differences window.

Comment: I'll give that a shot tomorrow if nothing else turns up.  I don't have ready access to a *nix box at work; and the windows version looks somewhat cumbersome to setup.

Comment: Apologies @DanNeely - you mentioned KDiff so I assumed you also had access to a linux system.

Comment: Oh.  KDiff's built into TortiseSVN/HG and is widely available on windows now.  Having to setup python shouldn't be a showstopper; but means it's not a point and click install.

Comment: Just double clicking on files didn't get me anything beyond what I'd gotten elsewhere; but meld let me do a multi-select and then run compare from the context menu to launch dozens of file diff tabs at once that I could quickly cycle through.

Comment: Oops - you're interface must behave differently to mine. Glad it still offers useful functionality though!